# Runtime Error on CodeForces - BeautifulMatrix

Tags: python, matrix, runtime-error

I was trying to solve the problem **263A - Beautiful Matrix**, but I get a Runtime error

[Here is the description](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/263/A)

And my code:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = []
for i in range(5):
      matrix.append(list(map(int, input().split())))

arr = np.array(matrix)
loc =  list(np.argwhere(arr == 1)[0])

x1, y1, x2, y2 = loc[0], loc[1], 2, 2

print(abs(x1-x2)+abs(y1-y2)) # Manhattan distance
```

Any help or pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The runtime error is due to the use of numpy library.
I'm not sure, but you cannot use these kind of libraries in codeforces.
Try to do this question without using this library.

Also if you're stuck, try reading the editorial.